# Video Uploading on youtube issue

Tags: ios, youtube

How can we upload the video through iPhone App pro-grammatically, can any one please provide me some sample code for the same.  I am using YouTube Direct Lite for iOS sample code with GTLR library. But Give 403 error:Disallow_useragent. I am using SFSafariviewcontroller,then app show me following error "please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there."   copy paste the code but not work!

Comment: Did you find a solution?